# PHP scraping - auto-update

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I want to display some charts based on the data I am scraping from a website, I want to know if there is any way to auto-update the data every time the site does.
Thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far? How about an ajax request that checks at intervals for changes and updates the chart if something has changed?

Comment: I thought in using ajax, I still don't know where to start using it, that's why I want to make a clear plan, so please if you can explain your idea a bit more, thanks.

Comment: There are many ways to "auto-update the data every time the site does". But please show your efforts here. If you want to update only on site refresh, you do not need even AJAX. If you want to update every few seconds the chart, then you can utilize AJAX calls that will pull the new data and then update the proper DOM selectors on your webpage. But try gong through tutorials and online examples before just asking how to do it without really trying..

Comment: @Ron, well I've searched online before asking here, and I did my efforts, my code is actually fine, I only need the part when I auto-update the data, and it's fine if the users refresh the data because it gets updated on the site every 4-5 days so it's useless to check it every few seconds or so, all I asked for was the idea behind auto-updating this database after a period of time without me doing it manually.

Comment: You want to auto-update the Database contents, or the webpage contents? To update the Database itself you would need a script that will add new data, possibly via CRON.. as we do not have ANY insight where your data is coming from, no example code, just guesses. If you add example code, formulate your question better, you might get the right answer much sooner.

Comment: I'll add some code, till then, yes I want to auto-update the DB contents, am inserting the data using a model file, the data are coming from what I've fetched and set into 4 variables, when scarping the website I put what needed into 4 variables, and then inserting these variables into my DB.

Comment: Well then the file that scrapes the web and produces those 4 vars can be automated, to run on it's own, and auto insert those variables within the DB. You can use CRON to run it on given intervals

Comment: Thank you very much @Ron, I've been already searching for the CRON and I guess this is what am looking for, I appreciate your time, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update your Database, you can use CRON to run the script, which scrapes the Web, prepares the variables, and inserts them into your DB.

Once inserted, your website upon refresh will pull the new data from the DB and show the chart with the updated info.

You can search for `Cron examples` to add your script to run periodically.